# Structure of $U_{2^k}$ for $k\geq 3$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that the group $U_{p^k}$ is cyclic for $p$ odd prime. But the prime $2$ behaves a little differently. The group $U_{2^k}$ is not cyclic for $k\geq 3$.

I want to show that $$U_{2^k}=\{\pm 5^i:0\leq i\leq 2^{k-2}\}.$$

Thus I want to show that $U_{2^k}\simeq \mathbb {Z_2\times Z_{2^{k-2}}}$, I worked with some particular examples like $U_{16}$ but could not figure out how to proceed in general.

Can someone give me a detailed proof/discussion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A detailed proof can be founded in An Introduction to The Theory of Groups 2nd ed. by Joseph J. Rotman, Theorem 5.44 page 120.

The main idea is to prove that $U_{2^k}$ is the direct product of $5$ and $-1$.